# Find PHP files in my WP site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created my own site using `wordpress` and I want to edit some code in some `PHP` files, but I don't know how to find my code file in the host.  Can someone tell me how to find these files?

Comment: So, do you know in what path did you install wordpress? What are you looking for, exactly, among these php files?

Comment: and where are you trying to edit from? Because, if you know the path, then you could do that from command line using vim, right? (however, it's not advisable to edit a core file)

Comment: i have some spam file and want to delete it where i find with `http://spamcheckr.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit in this files because source file is about server side.you can find the css files but not the source files. however, it's not advisable to edit a core file.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution to find out source file by any tool. because source file is about server side. you can find out css file name or path by firebug tool, but not the path of source code file.